# Chrome crashes when using robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Hi there i am **scraping** ADs data from olx using robotframework with my browser as chrome. The process works like this: it iterates over the ads click each ad **scrapes** the data then return on the previous page and then does the same. The problem is that after a certain limit lets say after **scraping** the data for the 320th AD the browser crashes. Is there anyway i can stop this or any way i can continue with my iteration after the crash. I new at this

Comment: Can you please share logs generated by the framework to understand the issue in more detail.

Comment: It might be a Chrome/Chromedriver issue. I have had similar problems with long RPA loops. One workaround is to close and open browser regularly.

Comment: fyi it's __scraping__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapping